# MYSQL SELECT only if rows are less than 5

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, count

i have a table named iv6_posts
i want to select records only if records are less than 5 rows
it should be in one query

something like this:

```
   select IF((select count(*) from iv6_posts)<5,select * from iv6_posts,null)
```

Comment: use rowcount fuction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that with plain `WHERE` since `COUNT()` is a group function and you can't use plain `HAVING` since it will group rows into one.

Instead you'll have to evaluate total count in distinct query and combine it with, for instance, `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  iv6_posts.*
FROM 
  iv6_posts
    CROSS JOIN 
      (
       SELECT 
         COUNT(1) AS c
       FROM 
         iv6_posts
      ) AS init
WHERE
  c<5
```

Check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0544/5) for it.